# DBI::Sybase data-conversion resulted in overflow

Tags: perl, sybase, dbi, freetds

I am writing a Perl script that is using the DBI module and is connecting to a Sybase DB. I am calling a stored procedure (one that I don't have access to so I cannot post sample code) and when I get data back I get an error that reads "error_handler: Data-conversion resulted in overflow". I still get data back and after doing some intensive research it seems that some data types in the columns (such as BigInt, nvarchar, etc) are the culprits. Now the question is, how can I fix this? Can this be fixed on the client side or can it only be fixed on the server side?

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:Sybase:server=$server", $username, $password, {PrintError => 0}) or die;
$dbh->do("use $database") or die;
my $sql = &getQuery;
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql) or die;
$sth->execute() or die;
while ($rowRef = $sth->fetchrow_arrayref) #Error seems to occur here
{
     #Parse through each row
}
```

Part of the FreeTDS 0.82 log that explains the problem:

```
_ct_bind_data(): column 7 is type 38 and has length 8
_ct_get_server_type(0)
_ct_get_client_type(type 38, user 0, size 8)
cs_convert(0x18dfed40, 0x7fff73216050, 0x18e44250, 0x7fff73215fa0, 0x18e387c0, 0x18e45a64)
_ct_get_server_type(30)
_ct_get_server_type(0)
converting type 127 (8 bytes) to type = 47 (9 bytes)
cs_convert() calling tds_convert
cs_convert() tds_convert returned 10
cs_prretcode(0)
cs_convert() returning  CS_FAIL
cs_convert-result = 1
```

Comment: I don't use DBD::Sybase but I use a load of other DBDs. I doubt anyone is going to answer this question without more information unless it is a known bug. At the very least post some of your Perl calling the procedure, list the schema and examples of data as it should be returned and how you get it.

Comment: This is a FreeTDS warning.  What we don't know is whether `DBD::Sybase` is internally making the wrong assumption, whether you can wrap the stored procedure call with clever SQL to force a proper type conversion, etc.

Turn on ["function trace and info"](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/freetdsconf.htm) debugging in your driver, and you should see what source type and octet length is being converted into what destination type and octet length.

Comment: Hi, I have done what you asked and I believe I have found the culprit. What FreeTDS is trying to do is that it's trying to convert a BigInt value (it's a 10-digit number) into a string that's 9 bytes long. Since there is more than 9 digits in the value there is an overflow. I do not know if this error is coming from the database side or if it's a bug in FreeTDS. For the record I am using FreeTDS 0.82

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem with FreeTDS. Please post here if you know the bug has been fixed and if you have the access and power to fix that bug. thx.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is on the FreeTDS side. I've had the same problem before and successfully fixed it by converting the returned fields to `varchar` in the `select` statement.

Given you don't have access to modify the original query, you can do some regex search and replace on the returned `$sql` variable in your code. In particular, if the original query has a part that looks like

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM ...
```

After you retrieve the query statement, you may run

```
my $new_sql;
if ($sql =~ /SELECT\s+(.*)\s+FROM/i) {  # match selected field string
    my $field_str = $1;
    my @fields = split ",", $field_str; # parse individual fields
    map s/\s//g, @fields;               # get rid of spaces
    my $new_str = join ", ", (map {sprintf "convert(varchar, $_)"} @fields);    # construct new query string
    my $quoted_field_str = quotemeta($field_str);   # prepare regex replacement string
    $new_sql = $sql;    
    $new_sql =~ s/$quoted_field_str/$new_str/i  # actual replacement
}
print $new_sql;
```

Of course, if your original statement is more complex, you should print it out and check how to modify it with a generic replacement bearing the same spirit. Alternatively, you can ask your DBA (or whoever has access to the stored procedure) to modify the actual query directly.

Hope this helps.